# why facebook is not working in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Facebook.com is not running in I frame anyone now the reason.

```
<iframe name="iframe1" src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Maybe you should check the developer logs. Do they block iframe use in HTTP headers?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts suppose they blocked then what is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 9):

Facebook.com doesn't allow for it's main page to be included in `iframe`, because they set `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header to `DENY`.

If you look in your console, you'll see:

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

If you want to get around this you can:

1. If you develop only for yourself, you can use browser plugin, for example: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe
2. However, it'd be best if you'll just use plugins they've exposed for developers: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins.

Comment: same problem was happening with google but it resolved when i tried <iframe id="if1" width="100%" height="254" style="visibility:visible" src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search"></iframe> is there any same solution for facebook ?

Comment: I don't think so. Facebook blocks including itself in `<iframe>` unless it's a plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins.